# Global error filter catches no exceptions from services, only controllers

Tags: javascript, exception, nestjs

I have an api NestJS where I implemented an error filter to catch all kinds of exceptions. In main.ts I set the api to use the filter globally.

Apparently, it only catches the errors in the controllers, because when I throw an exception in the context of service, the exception is thrown in the console and the api falls.

main.ts:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { HttpExceptionFilter } from './exception-filters/http-exception.filter';
import { AllExceptionsFilter } from './exception-filters/exception.filter';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter());

  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('API Agendamento.Vip')
    // .setDescription('')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .build();

  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
  // app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter());
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001);
}
bootstrap();
```

in a service method these exceptions are thrown

```
  if (err) { throw new InternalServerErrorException('error', err); }

  if (!user) { throw new NotFoundException('device info missing'); }

  if (!user.active) { throw new HttpException('active error', 400); }
```

my exception filter:

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost, HttpException, HttpStatus, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from 'fastify';

@Catch()
export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response: FastifyReply<any> = ctx.getResponse();
    const request: FastifyRequest = ctx.getRequest();

    const status =
      exception instanceof HttpException
        ? exception.getStatus()
        : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    const objResponse = Object.assign(exception, {
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      path: request.req.url
    });

    response.status(status).send({
      objResponse
    });
  }
}
```

Exceptions are thrown on the Node console, causing the api to stop.

They are only captured by the filter if they are in the context of the Controller.

What can I do to get exceptions caught in the service as well?

Comment: can you show your exception filter?

Comment: @RalphJS, I edited and includes the exception filter

Comment: The three exceptions you are using are HttpExceptions, even adding that on the catch decorator doesn't work?, you can also try adding the filter to the global scope using APP_FILTER I'll add an example

Answer (score 2):

Having seen your filter we can try two things first adding the HttpException to the @Catch decorator (just for testing I beleive won't make any difference)

```
@catch(HttpException)
export class AllExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  /*your code*/
}
```

Then instead of using app.useGlobalFilters add in the app module the following:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_FILTER } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AllExceptionsFilter } from './exception-filters/exception.filter';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: AllExceptionFilter,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This will put the filter in the global scope and will give you the capability to use the global injector, this is the aproach I always use for Globals(Filters, Guards, Pipes) and have worked for me like a charm

Comment: intelligently did not work. Service keeps throwing exception on node console when exception throws on service

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was throwing exceptions from within the model method:

```
  async signInApp(dataLogin: DataLoginDto) {
        return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
            this.userModel.findOne({
                email: dataLogin.email
            }, (err, user) => {

                if (err) { throw new InternalServerErrorException('error', err); }

                if (!user) { throw new NotFoundException('device info missing'); }

// ...Code omitted
```

I changed the code by placing exceptions outside the scope of mongoose methods:

```
 async signInApp(dataLogin: DataLoginDto) {
        const user = await this.userModel.findOne({
            email: dataLogin.email
        }).select('password active').exec();

        if (!user) { throw new NotFoundException('user not found'); }

        if (!user.active) { throw new UnauthorizedException('unable to access your account'); }

// ...Code omitted
```

Comment: With this you will not control Internal server errors I have almost the same aproach but on express and it works like a charm, could be some behavior with the nestjs' logger and fastify

Comment: even if I add MongoError to @Catch()?